JavaFX MediaPlayer.seek() is very inaccurate
Playing an .mp4 video in JavaFX MediaPlayer.
Here is pseudo-code
MediaPlayer player   = new MediaPlayer(new Media("myVideo.mp4"));
Slider      progress = new Slider();    // progress slider

...
player.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progress.setMax(player.getDuration().toMillis());
    }
});

player.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
        progress.setValue(newValue.toMillis());
    }
});

progress.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        player.seek(Duration.millis(progress.getValue()));
    }
});

progress.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        player.seek(Duration.millis(progress.getValue()));

        System.out.println(player.getCurrentTime() + ":" + progress.getValue());
    }
});

Player.seek(...) is very inaccurate. After calling player.seek(), the actual time difference between the video player and the progress slider may vary from 40 milliseconds to 5 seconds.
I also tried to bind() as below, which doesn't solve the issue.
progress.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
                        () -> player.getTotalDuration().toMillis(),
                              player.totalDurationProperty()));

Other people point out an inaccuracy in the MediaPlayer.seek() method in earlier versions of javafx. It seems that the problem is still not fixed:
MediaPlayer seekTo method is not accurate
How to precisely synchronize time in video player and progress slider?
My environment is Mac OS, Java 22, Javafx 24-ea-15.

You will have a greater chance of receiving a useful answer if you edit the question to provide the [mcve] that replicates the issue using copy and paste without change or addition as was requested in the staging ground.

The question linked refers to an issue using an android media player that is unrelated to the JavaFX media player.

It's not been my experience that MediaPlayer::seek is inaccurate, at least not on the order of seconds. Can you provide a [mre]?
